# Trying to mock SharedPreferences using Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use Mockito to test a settings manager which saves data through `SharedPreferences`.

Since `SharedPreferences` makes use of `Context`, I need to use mock classes.

This is my settings manager class:

```
public class SettingsManager implements ISettingsManager {

    protected SharedPreferences prefs;

    public SettingsManager(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        this.prefs = prefs;
    }

    private boolean getBooleanPreference(String key) {
        return prefs.getBoolean(key, true);
    }

    private void setBooleanPreference(boolean enabled, String key) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, enabled);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

This is the test case I wrote:

```
Context mContext = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
SharedPreferences mSharedPreference = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.Editor.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
Mockito.when(mSharedPreference.edit()).thenReturn(mEditor);
Mockito.when(mEditor.commit()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(mEditor.putBoolean(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyBoolean())).thenReturn(mEditor);

SettingsManager manager = new SettingsManager(mSharedPreference);
boolean current = manager.areNotificationsEnabled();
manager.setNotificationsEnabled(!current);
boolean newValue = manager.areNotificationsEnabled();
Assert.assertTrue(newValue != current);
```

The problem is when I set the `setNotificationsEnabled` flag, the `newValue` remains the same of `current`: `SharedPreferences` does not persist data. How can I save data to `SharedPreferences` while testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) is an option for this kind of integration test.

Robolectric provides test doubles called "shadows" of common Android classes like `Context`, `SQLiteDatabase` and `SharedPreferences`. The tests you write run in `test` in your IDE (not `androidTest` on an emulator or test device) so it is easier to configure tools for test coverage.

The shadow `SharedPreference` is sandboxed as well so it won't interfere with the actual `SharedPreferences` on a device.

Comment: I'll give a try! Thank you :)

Comment: robolectrichas very bad docs. can you help me with any of docs for using robolectric.

Answer (score 2):

Convert this to an AndroidTest and use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` to get a context, this way you can use the class without mocking it

Comment: But in this way I couldn't afford on code coverage: when I run tests by selecting "Run with Code Coverage" I get this error: "Error running SettingsInstrumented...: Cannot find runner for SettingsInstrumented...". The value of android.defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunner in the build.gradle file is "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

Comment: @NicolaGiancecchi check this http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/test-coverage-report-for-android-application/ hope it helps